# Sending emails with sendgrid

Tags: mongodb, email, dns, sendgrid

I am trying to use sendgrid with MongoDB stitch，and I have a domain name already on namecheap. I set up the domian authentication already，but do I need to have an email address with my domain ready before using sendgrid on MongoDB？I am not quite how everything works with sendgrid and its api. Anyone could help explain it a bit more？

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Can you be more specific what you want to achieve? 
If it's just about sending Emails with SendGrid, I'd start with [this guide](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started#how-to-send-an-api-email)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A bit more details about my case, I have a domain and I did domain authentication with the domain on sendgrid, the question is do I need to register a email with my domain name, which I dont have yet,  in order to have sendgrid help sending email using email address with my domain name in it？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [verify the sender address](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity) that you want to use. You can do that either for the entire domain (with domain authentication) or just a single sender. As you've already done the domain authentication, you are good. [This guide](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started#how-to-send-an-api-email) should enable you to send emails with a snippet that looks like this:

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY>>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"john.doe@example.com","name":"John Doe"}],"subject":"Hello, World!"}],"content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}],"from":{"email":"sam.smith@example.com","name":"Sam Smith"},"reply_to":{"email":"sam.smith@example.com","name":"Sam Smith"}}'
```